# How write the variational form of differential equations in latex?

Tags: math-mode, equations, amsmath

I am specifically trying to write this equation:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! And where is the problem?

Comment: I am having trouble with the RHS. for that, I am trying this `\arg_{\phi\in W}{inf I(\phi)} ` but that's not working.  Probably, there's something wrong in how I write it, but I cannot find a suitable command.

Comment: Please advise if `\phi\in W` should be centered below "inf" or below "arg inf".

Comment: It should be below "inf". Thanks.

Comment: In my opinion, it doesn't make sense for `\phi \in W` to be centered below "inf". That suggests that `\arg` is an operator being applied to `\inf ...`, which of course is not and cannot be the case. Centering below `\arginf` seems more sensible—and is also, in my experience, far more common.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You want

1. the “arg” operator to act on what follows;
2. the “inf” operator with limit “phi in W”;
3. the set which you compute the infimum of.

Just do

```
\arg \inf_{\phi\in W} \{ I(\phi) \}
```

if you are in a display. If you're in an inline formula

```
\arg \inf\limits_{\phi\in W} \{ I(\phi) \}
```

but this is not recommended as it spoils line spacing.

Here's a full example also showing the spacing issues.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

This is the requested formula in a display
\[
\phi^{\star} = \arg \inf_{\phi\in W} \{ I(\phi) \}
\]
and you can look at what happens if you have the formula inline, with
the limits set below $\phi^{\star}=\arg \inf\limits_{\phi\in W} \{ I(\phi) \}$
where you see that the spacing between lines is uneven and bad. Instead, type
it in normally (some text added here just to produce more lines)
like $\phi^{\star}=\arg \inf_{\phi\in W} \{ I(\phi) \}$
and the spacing between lines will be even and smooth. Some other text
added here to fill some more lines.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Here are two possible solutions. In the first, `\phi\in W` is centered below "inf" -- similar to what's shown in your screenshot -- with a little "trick" to keep the space between "arg" and "inf" fairly tight. In the second solution, `\phi\in W` is centered below "arg inf".

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools} %for '\smashoperator' macro
\DeclareMathOperator*{\arginf}{\arg\inf}
\begin{document}
\[
\phi^{\star} = \arg\smashoperator[l]{\inf_{\phi\in W}} \{I(\phi)\}
\]

\[
\phi^{\star} = \arginf_{\phi\in W} \{I(\phi)\}
\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

Here's a solution with  `mathtools`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools} %loads amsmath
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\set}\{\}

\begin{document}

\[ \phi^{\boldsymbol{\star} }= \arg\inf_{\mathclap{\phi\in W}}\,\set[\big]{I(\phi)}\]%

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Sebastiano: I don't really understand: *what* should be smaller?

Comment: `\phi\in W` for my opinion is too big and go out the command `\inf`.